# How to use a class constructor has out parameters?

Tags: java, file

I wanted to created a `BufferedWriter` instance but I am just curious if the following way may cause memory leak issues or something similar that i should be warned

```java
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(destFile, false));
```

Is the following way the best practice? why? Would someone explain for each approach?

```java
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(destFile, false)
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
```

Comment: Java has garbage collection: once there are no references left to something, that thing will get removed from memory, including anything it points to that _only it_ points to.

Comment: `BufferedWriter` class is an example of the [decorator pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+decorator+pattern). Closing the `BufferedWriter` will also close the [wrapped] `FileWriter`. In my opinion, there is no difference between the two code snippets in your question.

Comment: I have more query .... if you really can show me one good reference to proof in above code snippet in the first approach, the FileWriter keeps an anonymous memory at parameter ... right?

Comment: Why would the first cause a memory leak and not the latter? Why would either? In a garbage collected language, memory leaks occur when an object remains strongly referenced after the program no longer needs it. In both of your code snippets, the `BufferedWriter` will have a strong reference to the `FileWriter`. In other words, based solely on what you've provided us, there is no difference between your two approaches (except perhaps a difference in readability, depending on your preferences).

Comment: I agree with you @Slaw

Comment: I also agree with @Abra

Comment: Then is your question answered? If not, then I do not understand what you're asking. Perhaps you have a misunderstanding regarding how garbage collectors work, in which case [ruakh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945529/is-anonymous-object-references-in-java-are-always-unreachable-to-gc?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment137413904_77945529) on your other question should help.

Comment: What is an "out parameter"?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter#BufferedWriter(java.io.Writer) has output buffer in parameter - I was wrong before and assumed the second approach is correct but as answered there is no difference but readability

Comment: Ah, so by "out parameter" you meant the parameter named "out".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no practical difference between the two approaches.

In theory, *both* versions can leak a `FileWriter` if the creation of the `BufferedWriter` fails.  This would persist until the garbage collector determines the `FileWriter` is unreachable, runs the finalizer<sup>1</sup> and closes it.

In practice, the only scenario in which that can happen is if there is an OOME during the allocation or construction phases of the creation of the `BufferedWriter` instance.  That scenario is:

1. highly unlikely to occur, and
2. going to trigger a **full** garbage collection.

The full GC will result in the unreachable `FileWriter` being found to be unreachable and closed.  Thus the duration of the theoretical leak will be very short ... and it won't have any impact.

In short, there is nothing to worry about here.

---

<sup>1 - If you are reading this in a few years time, you may find that this is no longer done using a finalizer.  Finalizers are on the way out.  It is likely that some other JVM mechanism will be used to close "lost" file descriptors<sup>2</sup>.

2 - It is leakage of file descriptors that matters here, not the miniscule amount of Java heap memory associated with a `FileWriter` object.</sup>